# in MySQL, how to compare five values in the same row and get the output of a particular column in the same row?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms

In the MySQL table, I have four rows and six columns excluding the primary key. The column names are
value 1,value 2, value 3, value 4, value 5 and output. The user enters the input form WinForms app
for columns value 1 to 5. For example, Value 1 = A, value 2 = B, value 3 = C, value 4 = D, value 5 = E and output = Goods. Now, I want to compare all the five values A = B = C = D = E then get the output value **Goods** and shows to the user.

[image: The value A,B,C,D,E enter by the user and The input TextBox also enter by the user. when the user click Add button it add to the database. When user enter the click the Get Button for the same value it validate and shows the output to the output Box]

[image: This is how the database I want]

[image: This is how my input and output I want]

```
string connection = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = 
sample; password = 12345678";
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
        MySqlCommand cmd;
        try
        {                
            con.Open();
            cmd = con.CreateCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO result(value 1, value 2, 
value 3, value 4, value 5) VALUES (@value 1, @value 2, @value 3, 
@value 4, @value 5)";
cmd.Parameters.Add("@value 1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = 
value1textbox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value 2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value 
= value2textbox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value 3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value 
= value3textbox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value 4", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value 
= value4textbox.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@value 5", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value 
= value5textbox.Text;
            
            if (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Saved Successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
            }
            
        }
        catch(Exception ex)  
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.StackTrace);
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
}
```

Now, The values added successfully but I don't know how to compare the same row values and get the output of the same row output column.

*Thank You in Advanced for your help !!!!*

Comment: Why don't you just select based on value1-5?

Comment: I'm new to MySQL and WinForms C# so please can you explain me in detail

Comment: concat the input values and select from the table where the table concatenated values match ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
string connection = "server = localhost; user id = root; database = 
sample; password = 12345678";
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(connection);
MySqlCommand cmd;

try
{
    con.Open();

    // Create a SQL command to retrieve the output based on input values
    cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "SELECT output FROM constellation " +
                     "WHERE value1 = @value1 AND value2 = @value2 " +
                     "AND value3 = @value3 AND value4 = @value4 AND value5 = @value5";
    
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value1", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input1TextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value2", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input2TextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value3", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input3TextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value4", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input4TextBox.Text;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@value5", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = input5TextBox.Text;

    // Execute the query
    object result = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
    
    if (result != null)
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = result.ToString();
    }
    else
    {
        outputTextBox.Text = "No matching data found.";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
}
```

I just change the command text from your code and `ExecuteNonQuery` to `ExecuteScalar` (because we just have 1 output value there). If value is not unique, you may add `order by` and `LIMIT 1` to just get TOP 1.